# JDBC PreparedStatement, how to select and insert?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm trying to execute stored procedure via JDBC, which has simple structure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE test
AS BEGIN
SELECT ...
INSERT ...
END
```

The problem is that **insert is not happened**. When I execute this procedure in management studio, then it's all right.

```
String query = "EXEC test";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
st.execute();
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet(); //result set is correct
int count = st.getUpdateCount(); //returns -1
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try change the value of  query to `String query = "{call test()}"` and then you can use

> CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(query);
>
> > cs.execute();

you can need commit to view your changes in the database.

> > conn.commit();

Comment: unfortunately, insert still doesn't happen

Comment: I've added conn.commit(), and insert is executed now, but 2 times for some reason

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Call was executed 2 times from different places. I've set auto commit to true and it's working fine now. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Since its a procedure you're trying to call, you need to use a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures.

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(query);
```

Also, your query needs to be

```
String query = "{call test}"; 
// exec is used to execute the procedure from the sql console as such
// To execute a procedure using the java code, use call proc.
```

Comment: Did you encountered any exception? Plz share it also.

Comment: This code works, I mean no exception, but insert still doesn't happen

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a callable statement instead of prepared statement

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
try {
   String SQL = "{call procedureName}";
   cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
   . . .
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   . . .
}
finally {
   . . .
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, insert still doesn't happen

Comment: you should execute the statement and commit the transaction for the insert to get into effect.